# How to deny access to all and allow only certain file types on sub domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 different domains pointing to the same root directory

```
www.domain1.co.uk
a.domain2.com
```

The purpose of this is to serve static content from a.domain2.com

I dont wont anyone to access my site via a.domain2.com so I need allow only certain file types (js|css|jpg|png|gif|avi|wmv|mpg|wav|mp3|txt|rtf|doc|xls|rar|zip|tar|gz|tg) and deny everything else to prevent full site loading via a.domain2.com

Obviously the .htaccess file resides in root directory an is valid for both domains. How do I create a rule to achieve what I described above.

I also need to point, that following rewrite (to redirect non-www to www) is already in place on this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain1\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain1.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that in your `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine On

#prohibits other types with a.domain2.com 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(?:js|css|jpg|png|gif|avi|wmv|mpg|wav|mp3|txt|rtf|doc|xls|rar|zip|tar|gz|tg)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# no other rewrite for a.domain2.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# add www and/or change domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain1\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain1.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I've noticed that you have changed my rewrite condition to add www.
I actually have more domains that points to the same root which I need to redirect to www.domain1.co.uk
I assume my original condition 
   ` RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$`
worked as a wild card. Does your suggested implementation mean that I can not longer use wild card for other domains ? or can I still use my initial rewrite condition?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$` means "not empty", and therefore in all cases. it does not matter. I just need to exclude a.domain2...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be using .htaccess, or mod_rewrite for that matter for this problem. Instead use a `VirtualHost` block in your main config file (httpd.conf) and deny access to anything that does not end with a certain extension:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "blah"
  ServerName www.domain1.co.uk
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "blah"
  ServerName a.domain2.com

  <FilesMatch ".+\.(?!(js|css|jpg|png|gif|avi|wmv|mpg|wav|mp3|txt|rtf|doc|xls|rar|zip|tar|gz|tg)$)[^\.]+?$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from All
  </FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have an access to config file. Why would you not recommend to use mod_rewrite ?

Comment: A carpenter has to attach 2 planks to each other. He has nails, screws and a length of rope. He also has a hammer, a brick and a kitchen knife. He could take the brick and hit the screw until it is through it, then use the rope to further secure it. Or he could use the nail, and the hammer. mod_rewrite is a module to internally or externally rewrite requests with a greater range of options than other modules do. You want to block access to a files using a specific domain name, and the best way to do that is by using the directives and blocks defined in the Apache core.